# Как переносить модули из одной virtual environment в другую

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Странный вопрос, но все же. Вот представим что у меня есть два виртуальных окружения со своими зависимостями. Я хочу подгрузить модулей. Пишу `pip install tensorflow`. Он на секунду весит более 500 мб так что при сельском интернете у бабули, это занятие не быстрое. Он установил мне модуль в первое виртуальное окружение. Теперь мне вдруг понадобилось работать на втором виртуальном окружении и надо подгружать tensorflow туда тоже. Можно ли достать версию из прошлого virtualenv, а не устанавливать его заново с интернетов ? Вплане, скопировать папки можно попытаться, а есть ли какая команда типо, pip copy from ..... ? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Все скачанные пакеты pip кладёт в кэш, так что при повторной установке они не будут заново качаться, а будут взяты из кэша. Если вы не чистили кэш, конечно

Comment: Я предполагал что так должно быть, не качать же одно и то же по 100 раз. только вот нужны какая-то определенная команда для загрузки из кеша, потому что если просто написать ```pip install tensorflow``` к примеру, то вместо того чтобы загрузить его из кеша он ждет интернет подключения. Так что это не та команда, а может подскажите какая нужна? Там есть параметр --cache dir, может его как-то надо использовать?

Comment: если вам нужна именно консольная команда, то можно встроенным копированием окружение перенести: cp -R folder1 folder2 (для unix)

Comment: @МаратАминов интернет-подключение всё равно нужно для того, чтобы скачать индекс пакетов и проверить последнюю версию. Но сами пакеты будут взяты из кэша, если он есть

Comment: Если же стоит задача работать полностью вообще совсем без интернета - возможно, стоит поставить какой-нибудь кэширующий прокси вроде [DevPI](https://github.com/devpi/devpi)